# Segmentation fault using string pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a C++ newbie, I'm trying to put in practice pointers with strings. The program I have made is just to store strings the user types in the command line. But I'm getting segfault, not sure why.

This is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//This code is meant to learn how to use pointers and strings
//Ask the user for who are they in the family and save it in string array!


void print_string (string* Value, int const nSize);
int get_names(string* Family_input);

int main ( int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{

  cout << "Tis program stores your family members\n";
  cout<< "Type the names and write 0 to exit\n";

  string familia_string;
  string* familia = &familia_string;

  int family_number;

  family_number=get_names(familia);  

  cout << "The family members are: ";  

  print_string(familia, family_number);

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}

int get_names(string* Family_input)
{
  int i=0;
  string input="";
  string old_input="";
  while (input!="0")
  {
    cout << "type " << i <<" member\n";
    //cin >> *(Family_input+i);
    //input=*(Family_input+i);
    cin >> input;
    *(Family_input + old_input.length()) = input;
    old_input=input;
    i++;
  }
  return i;

}

void print_string (string* Value, int const nSize)
{// I don't want to &psValue to be changed!
  for (int i=0; i<nSize; i++)
  {
     cout << *(Value+i) << " ";
     //&psValue++;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's because I'm not taking correctly the size of the string, or I'm not using correctly the pointer or is that I have to allocate memory before using the offset.

Comment: Show code here (minimal but complete example) and not on external sites. Also, C and C++ are not the same language, and "natural" solutions in one may not work in the other (so only tag the language you are writing / compiling).

Comment: What is your thinking behind `*(Family_input + old_input.length()) = input`?

Comment: [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and IDE debuggers are your friends. Learn how to use them and you will be able to hunt down the exact line that causes a segfault.

Comment: You're not writing in C, so don't play with `std::string*`, use [`std::string&`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As @kleszcz pointed out already, the line

```
*(Family_input + old_input.length()) = input;
```

is wrong. You are accessing memory that you are not supposed to.

The easiest fix is to change `get_names` slightly:

```
int get_names(string* Family_input)
{
   int i=0;
   string input="";
   while (input!="0")
   {
      cout << "type " << i <<" member\n";
      cin >> input;
      *Family_input += input; // Just keep on appending to the input argument.
      *Family_input += "\n"; // Add a newline to separate the inputs.
      i++;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Also change `print_string` to:

```
void print_string (string* Value)
{
   cout << *Value;
}
```

Of course, `print_string` has become so simple, you don't need to have it at all.

You could change `get_names` to use a reference argument instead of a pointer argument. This is a better practice.

```
int get_names(string& Family_input)
{
   int i=0;
   string input="";
   while (input!="0")
   {
      cout << "type " << i <<" member\n";
      cin >> input;
      Family_input += input; // Just keep on appending to the input argument.
      Family_input += "\n"; // Add a newline to separate the inputs.
      i++;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Then, change the call to `get_names`. Instead of using

```
family_number=get_names(familia);
```

use

```
family_number=get_names(familia_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get seg fault because you haven't allocate memory for an array of strings.

```
*(Family_input + old_input.length()) = input;
```

This is total nonsense. If you'd have an array you increment index only by one not by length of string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save different names in different string objects I would suggest:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void print_string(string** Value, int const nSize);
void get_names(string** Family_input, int count);


int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[]) {

cout << "This program stores your family members\n";
int family_number;
cout << "Types the number of family members";
cin >> family_number;

/*allocate the number of string pointers that you need*/
string** familia = new string*[family_number];

cout << "Type the names\n";

get_names(familia, family_number);

cout << "The family members are: ";

print_string(familia, family_number);

cout << endl;

return 0;
}

void get_names(string** Family_input, int count) {

for(int i = 0 ; i < count; i++){
    cout << "type " << i << " member\n";
    /*create a string obj in the heap memory*/
    string *input = new string ("");
    // using that way you get only a single word
    cin >> *input;
    /*create a string object on the stack and put its pointer in the family_array*/
    Family_input[i] = input;
}
}

void print_string(string** Value, int const nSize) {
for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++) {
    cout << *(Value[i]) << " ";
}
}
```